# OnyToMany: SQLException occurs: Unknown column 'xxx' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to use unidirectional relationship for my JPA instances (Hibernate 4.3.10)
RegionalCountry -> RegionalArea1 -> RegionalArea2

```
@Entity
public class RegionalCountry {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 36)
    private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private String countryName;
    private String countryCode;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<RegionalArea1> regionalArea1;
    ...//getters&setters
}

@Entity
public class RegionalArea1 {    
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 36)
    private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private String area1Name;   
    private String area1Code;   

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<RegionalArea2> regionalArea2;
    ...//getters&setters
}

@Entity
public class RegionalArea2 {            
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 36)
    private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private String area2Name;   
    private String area2Code;
    ...//getters&setters
}
```

Then I want to use Spring JpaRepository to fetch the country and its regional area instances by country code:

```
public interface RegionalCountryRepository extends JpaRepository<RegionalCountry, UUID> {   
    public RegionalCountry findOneByCountryCode(String countryCode);
}
```

When I call

```
regionalCountryRepository.findOneByCountryCode(countryCode);
```

SQLException occurs: `Unknown column 'regionalar0_.regional_country' in 'field list'`

the same exception is for `regionalCountryRepository.findAll();`

Is there a way to use unidirectional relationship between regional instances and do not get this error?

Surprisingly, unit tests with embedded db work well for the code above, but when we deal with the real MySQL database the exception occurs.

```
@Test
public void testFindByCountryCode() {

    southernArea = new RegionalArea1();
    southernArea.setArea1Code("00");
    southernArea.setArea1Name("SOUTHERN");

    chejuDoArea = new RegionalArea1();      
    chejuDoArea.setArea1Code("00");
    chejuDoArea.setArea1Name("CHEJU-DO");

    korea = new RegionalCountry();
    korea.setCountryName("Korea, Republic of");
    korea.setCountryCode("KOR");
    korea.setRegionalArea1s(Arrays.asList(southernArea, chejuDoArea));

    repository.save(korea);     
    RegionalCountry countryFetched = repository.findOneByCountryCode("KOR");
    Assert.assertNotNull(countryFetched);
}
```

**Update:** the schema is the following

```
CREATE TABLE REGIONAL_AREA2(
    UUID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,    
    AREA2CODE VARCHAR(255),
    AREA2NAME VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE REGIONAL_AREA1(
    UUID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,    
    AREA1CODE VARCHAR(255),
    AREA1NAME VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE REGIONAL_AREA1_REGIONAL_AREA2(
    REGIONAL_AREA1_UUID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    REGIONAL_AREA2_UUID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
);  


CREATE TABLE REGIONAL_COUNTRY(
    UUID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,  
    COUNTRY_CODE VARCHAR(255),
    COUNTRY_NAME VARCHAR(255)
);        

CREATE TABLE REGIONAL_COUNTRY_REGIONAL_AREA1(
    REGIONAL_COUNTRY_UUID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    REGIONAL_AREA1_UUID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Is this schema generated by Hibernate?

Comment: yes, something wrong with it?

Comment: No. Looks ok :) Please add SQL which produce the error.

Comment: SQL query is generated automatically in RegionalCountryRepository. For example failed findAll() generates 'select * from regional_country'

Comment: You can enable SQL logging in Hibernate and get a full SQL request. It is not like `select * from regional_country` cause of an eager loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers but the problem was in `REGIONAL_COUNTRY_REGIONAL_AREA1` table column names. Postfix **_UUID** at the end of the column name confuses MySQL.
It's possible to fix this problem renaming columns of intermediate datatables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS REGIONAL_AREA1_REGIONAL_AREA2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS REGIONAL_AREA1_REGIONAL_AREA2;

CREATE TABLE REGIONAL_AREA1_REGIONAL_AREA2(
    REGIONAL_AREA1 VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    REGIONAL_AREA2 VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
);  

CREATE TABLE REGIONAL_COUNTRY_REGIONAL_AREA1(
    REGIONAL_COUNTRY VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    REGIONAL_AREA1 VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I am not sure this is a reason. You just have the `REGIONAL_COUNTRY` column now in the table.

Comment: And that's what JPA is looking for: Unknown column 'regionalar0_.regional_country' in 'field list'

Comment: But why it looks `'regionalar0_.regional_country` not `regionalar0_.regional_country_uuid` ?

Comment: I supposed that it should look for regional_country_uuid too. BTW the db schema was generated automatically by H2 database. I created RegionalCountry, RegionalArea1, RegionalArea2 instances, save them into database and export to a file with 'SCRIPT SIMPLE NOSETTINGS to <scriptFilename>' Looks like those scripts are reliable but because of those scripts I had to post this question.

Comment: So you don't use an auto generation for MySQL tables?

Comment: No, it was created with H2 database and persisted classes.

Comment: MySQL was confused by the name automatically created by H2, better?

Comment: No, I think if you will let Hibernate to create a schema for MySQL it creates valid column names and will be use them without errors. It will be interesting if you do it.

Comment: And your SQL for creating new tables is not valid because of you don't recreate constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several reasons:

1. I do not see any mapping from your class variables to table field `regional_country`. Please make sure to use annotation `@Column` to specify the correct table field which the variable maps to. For instance, if variable countryCode maps to table field country_code, you should annotate like this: `@Column(name = "country_code") private int countryCode;`
2. For variables `private String countryName; private String countryCode;` if they have a mapping field in your db schema, please use `@Column` to annotate them
3. It would be helpful if you provide more information about your question: e.g., your db schema.

Comment: 1,2. There is no need to use @Column annotation because in my case JPA automatically converts the camel case of the field name to use underscores.
3. added schema above

Comment: OK. I can only provide a possible reason: 1. Based on the facts that (i) it works in the embedded DB but not MySQL, and (ii) you have the `ImprovedNamingStrategy` applied, there should be something inconsistent between your program and your MySQL settings. One clue is why not check if your MySQL table name is case sensitive? And change all the table names to lower case, and explicitly annotate the tables in your classes, such that all are consistent? Frankly speaking I do not trust all the libraries that automate your configs. Hope this would help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your problem using just Hibernate `Session` without any `JpaRepository`. I have to change mapping for all collection associations from `List` to `Set` cause of the "cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags" error

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<RegionalArea1> regionalArea1;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<RegionalArea2> regionalArea2;
```

Everything works fine without any errors. May be, It will help you too. If It will no help:

Hibernate thinks that the `REGIONAL_COUNTRY_REGIONAL_AREA1` join table has the `regional_country` column, but this table has the `REGIONAL_COUNTRY_UUID`. So try to specify join column names by `@JoinTable` annotation, or recreate database schema, or change the  naming strategy, if you specify it.

SQL generated by Hibernate for search country by country code

```
 select
        this_.f_uuid as f_uuid1_3_2_,
        this_.f_country_code as f_countr2_3_2_,
        this_.f_country_name as f_countr3_3_2_,
        regionalar2_.fk_regional_country as fk_regio1_4_4_,
        regionalar3_.f_uuid as fk_regio2_4_4_,
        regionalar3_.f_uuid as f_uuid1_0_0_,
        regionalar3_.f_area1code as f_area2_0_0_,
        regionalar3_.f_area1name as f_area3_0_0_,
        regionalar4_.fk_regional_area1 as fk_regio1_1_5_,
        regionalar5_.f_uuid as fk_regio2_1_5_,
        regionalar5_.f_uuid as f_uuid1_2_1_,
        regionalar5_.f_area2code as f_area2_2_1_,
        regionalar5_.f_area2name as f_area3_2_1_ 
    from
        spring_regional_countries this_ 
    left outer join
        spring_regional_countries_regional_area1s regionalar2_ 
            on this_.f_uuid=regionalar2_.fk_regional_country 
    left outer join
        spring_regional_area1s regionalar3_ 
            on regionalar2_.fk_regional_area1=regionalar3_.f_uuid 
    left outer join
        spring_regional_area1s_regional_area2s regionalar4_ 
            on regionalar3_.f_uuid=regionalar4_.fk_regional_area1 
    left outer join
        spring_regional_area2s regionalar5_ 
            on regionalar4_.fk_regional_area2=regionalar5_.f_uuid 
    where
        this_.f_country_code=?
```